# How to include externel js file in ejs file in response which is used in another div in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

i have facing a problem like. i have a ejs view. in that view i need to update a div element content dynamically. for that reason i use fetch request to server which in response render an ejs file also. on that ejs file i have attached  external js and css files. css files are loaded correctly but my js files are not loaded. infact i don't see a request for the js file in chrome development tool network tab. here i give code and structures. Hope someone help!!!

my app.js

```
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.set("views", path.join(rootDir, "Views", "View"));
app.use(express.static(path.join(rootDir, "public")));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

i have added a static path. my js file location.
Public
-js
--mobile
---addBike.js
My mainDashboard.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title>Riders Point::Trusfull Point For Riders</title>
<%-include("../../template/favIconHTML.ejs")%>
<%-include("../../template/NavBarCssLink.ejs")%>
<%-include("../../template/adminDashboardCSSLink.ejs")%>
</head>
<body>
<%- include("../../template/overlay.ejs")%> <%-
include("../../template/navBarHTML.ejs")%>
<section class="scrollingContent">
  <section class="controlPanel">
    <div class="addBike btn navDes" data-url="/addBike">Add Bike</div>
  </section>
  <div class="viewArea"></div>
</section>
<script src="/js/mobile/navBarJS.js"></script>
<script src="/js/mobile/adminDashboard.js"></script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

when i click on addBike div then the fetch request executes in adminDashboard.js. adminDashboard.js is given below.

```
let viewArea = document.querySelector(".viewArea");
[...controlBtns].forEach((btn) => {
btn.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
let url = btn.getAttribute("data-url");
fetch(url, {
  method: "GET",
})
  .then((response) => {
    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error("Failed To Fetch");
    } else {
      return response.text();
    }
  })
  .then((data) => {
    let div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = data;
    viewArea.innerHTML = div.innerHTML;
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    viewArea.innerHTML = "";
    viewArea.innerText = "Data Not Found";
  });
    });
  });
```

the response of this request is given below

```
exports.getAddBike = (req, res, next) => {
res.render("user/addBike");
};
```

then the viewArea div gets the ejs file and loads css files but not loads the js file. addBike.ejs file is given below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title>Riders Point::Trusfull Point For Riders</title>
<%-include("../../template/addBikeCSSLink.ejs")%>
</head>
<body>
<div class="mainContainer">
  <div class="headline">Add Bike</div>
  <div class="bikeInfo">
    <table border="1" cellspacing="0">
      <tr>
        <th colspan="2" align="center">Bike Information</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Bike Name</th>
        <td><input type="text" class="bikeName" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Brand</th>
        <td><input type="text" class="brand" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>CC</th>
        <td><input type="text" class="cc" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Regular Price</th>
        <td><input type="text" class="regPrice" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Offer Price</th>
        <td><input type="text" class="offPrice" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Bike Type</th>
        <td><input type="text" class="bikeType" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Distributor</th>
        <td><input type="text" class="dist" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Model Year</th>
        <td><input type="text" class="modYear" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Brand Origin</th>
        <td><input type="text" class="brandOrigin" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Assemble In</th>
        <td><input type="text" class="assIn" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="2" align="center">Engine</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Engine Type</th>
        <td><input type="text" class="engType multipleInput" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Displacement</th>
        <td><input type="text" class="disp" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Maximum Power</th>
        <td><input type="text" class="maxPow" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Maximum Torque</th>
        <td><input type="text" class="maxTorq" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Bore</th>
        <td><input type="text" class="bore" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Stroke</th>
        <td><input type="text" class="stroke" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Compression Ratio</th>
        <td><input type="text" class="compR" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Valves</th>
        <td><input type="text" class="valves" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Fuel Supply</th>
        <td><input type="text" class="fSup" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>No Of Cylinders</th>
        <td><input type="text" class="nOCyl" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Engine Cooling</th>
        <td><input type="text" class="engCool" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Starting Method</th>
        <td><input type="text" class="startM" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="2" align="center">Transmission</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Transmission Type</th>
        <td><input type="text" class="tt" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>No Of Gears</th>
        <td><input type="text" class="nG" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Clutch Type</th>
        <td><input type="text" class="cT" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="2" align="center">Mileage & Top Speed</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Mileage</th>
        <td><input type="text" class="mil" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Top Speed</th>
        <td><input type="text" class="tS" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="2" align="center">Chassis & Suspension</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Chassis Type</th>
        <td><input type="text" class="chT" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Front Suspension</th>
        <td><input type="text" class="fS" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Rear Suspension</th>
        <td><input type="text" class="rS" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="2" align="center">Brakes</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Front Brake Type</th>
        <td><input type="text" class="frBT" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Rear Brake Type</th>
        <td><input type="text" class="rrBT" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Braking System</th>
        <td><input type="text" class="brSys" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>ABS</th>
        <td><input type="text" class="abs" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="2" align="center">Wheels & Tires</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Front Tire Size</th>
        <td><input type="text" class="frTS" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Rear Tire Size</th>
        <td><input type="text" class="rrTS" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Tire Type</th>
        <td><input type="text" class="tireType" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Wheel Type</th>
        <td><input type="text" class="wt" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="2" align="center">Dimensions</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Overall Length</th>
        <td><input type="text" class="ovL" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Overall Width</th>
        <td><input type="text" class="ovW" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Height</th>
        <td><input type="text" class="height" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Ground Clearance</th>
        <td><input type="text" class="gcl" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Weight</th>
        <td><input type="text" class="weight" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Fuel Tank Capacity</th>
        <td><input type="text" class="fTCap" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Wheelbase</th>
        <td><input type="text" class="whBase" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Seat Height</th>
        <td><input type="text" class="seatH" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="2" align="center">Electricals</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Battery Voltage</th>
        <td><input type="text" class="batV" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Head Light</th>
        <td><input type="text" class="headL" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Tail Light</th>
        <td><input type="text" class="tailL" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Indicators</th>
        <td><input type="text" class="ind" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="2" align="center">Features</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Speedometer</th>
        <td><input type="text" class="speedMet" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Odometer</th>
        <td><input type="text" class="odoMet" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>RPM Meter</th>
        <td><input type="text" class="rpmMet" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Handle Type</th>
        <td><input type="text" class="handType" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Seat Type</th>
        <td><input type="text" class="seatTyp" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Passenger Grab Rail</th>
        <td><input type="text" class="passGRail" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Engine Kill Switch</th>
        <td><input type="text" class="engKS" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th colspan="2" align="center">
          Additional Feature <input type="checkbox" class="addFeat" />
        </th>
      </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
    </div>
    <script src="/js/mobile/addBike.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

everything loads correctly but only addBike.js is not loaded.
addBike.js is given below.

```
// one input multiple value handler
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
document.addEventListener("click", () => {
alert("click");
});
});
```

do anyone know why the addBike.js file is not loaded??? or how to load this js file.

Comment: @j-porter any idea??